# Alembic: how to use 2 revision folders for 1 database?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, database-migration, alembic

I've **2 applications** sharing **1 database**. It shouldn't be a problem if both applications only alter the schema of their *own* tables, but what if both applications want to modify the same table?

Is that even possible with Alembic?